# Can't store my new generated data in MongoDB

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I am building a small project where you can generate a random hex color and then save it to database. But I don't know what I am doing wrong because my data won't save to database.
So index.js is my main file where I am declaring routes. I am using ejs for templeting and a separate file in a public folder where I write my javascript code. Can you give me a hint? Should I somehow work on my JS file where I click the button to submit the hex code somewhere?

**index.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
const path = require('path');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Color = require('./models/hexColor');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/randColor', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true})
    .then(() => {
        console.log("MONGO CONNECTION OPEN")
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log("ERROR MONGO CONNECTION")
        console.log(err)
    })


app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use('/public', express.static('public'));
app.use(express.urlencoded({extended: true}));

app.get('/home', (req, res) => {
    res.render('homepage.ejs')
})

app.get('/hexColor', async (req, res) => {
    const color = await Color.find({});
    res.render('hexColor.ejs', { color });
})

app.post('/hexColor', async (req, res) => {
    const newColor = new Color(req.body)
    await newColor.save();
})



app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log("Listening!")
})
```

**hexColor.ejs**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../public/hexColor.css">
    <title>Hex Color Generator</title>
</head>
<body>

    <form action="/hexColor" method="POST">
        <div class="nav-container">
            <div>
                <h4 class="back-to-home">Home</h4>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h1>Hex Color Generator</h1>
            </div>
            <div>
                <h4>History</h4>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="btn-container">
            <button class="btn-generator">Click to generate</button>
        </div>

        <div class="color-container">
            <div class="square-container">
            
            </div>
        </div>
        <ul class="hex"></ul>
    </form>
   
    
 
    <script src="../public/hexColor.js"></script>
</body>
</html
```

**hexColor.ejs**

```
const homeBtn = document.querySelector(".back-to-home");
const btnGenerator = document.querySelector(".btn-generator");
const squareCont = document.querySelector(".square-container");
const ul = document.querySelector('.hex');

function hexChangeColor () {
    var randomColor = Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    var hexColor = `#${randomColor}`;
    return hexColor;
}

homeBtn.addEventListener('click', function () {
    window.location.href = 'http://localhost:3000/home'
})

btnGenerator.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    squareCont.style.backgroundColor = hexChangeColor();
    const li = document.createElement('LI');
    li.innerHTML = hexChangeColor();
    ul.appendChild(li);

})
```

**hexSchema.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const colorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    hex: {
        type: String
    }
})

const Color = mongoose.model('Color', colorSchema);
module.exports = Color;
```

Comment: Any error message?

Answer (score 0):

what you are getting in req.body?

Try by adding body-parser
https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser